# dynamic ORM in node.js+mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dynamic-data

Is it possible to create a model where the relationships are dynamically generated by the application?

I saw the KeystoneJS project that does a nice job of defining the model (see: http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#relationship-definitions)

But these need to be defined by node, I'm interested in creating these within the application. Are there any ORMs or framework projects that already do that? I I've seen frameworks like the MODxCMS that allow users to create additional fields, by putting everything from the custom (templatevar) values into one table.  think mongodb would be great for setting this up without this single table approach.

Any idea how to go about setting this kind of system up? I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) might help you here. And you may want to have a look at [mongo-relation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongo-relation) too.